# Display an image when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, submit

Sorry for being that upsetting, but this is my first time coding. I just wanted some advice.

After a lot of research, I haven't found any answer that I could understand for my question. I just need an image to be displayed when the input submit is clicked. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Data tracking </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="first script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Track your data</h1>
    <p>Would you like to know how many data a web site can track from you?</p>
    <form method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal data</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
            <br>
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
        <div></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()){
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $('body').append('<img src="cookie.png"></img>')
    });
});
```

I just cannot make the image "cookie.png", which is in the same folder as the html and the script files, to appear when submit is clicked and don't know why.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you submit the `form`, a refresh is done, so you won't see your image... You need to prevent default behaviour BUT better is to bind `submit` event of `form`, because user could still submit the `form` without clicking submit button. FYI, never use `name="submit"` inside a `form`, it overrides native submit DOM method

Comment: dumb question, but  are you including the jQuery library anywhere?? because you need it for your code to work

Comment: Use preventDefault(); before appending the image. So that the page won't refresh by default.

Comment: @PriyaRajaram Ya but then no datas are send to server

Comment: How can you expect to both submit the form, *and stay on the same page*, unless you use Ajax to submit it?

Comment: You have to describe what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Then you can use Ajax to send your data to server right?

Comment: @PriyaRajaram Ya that's correct!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*(UPDATED)* It will not follow the path of the script-file, but the folder of your html-file / URL! Make sure the picture is placed there.

But note that when submitting, the page will be forwarded to a fresh page / reloaded. So you can't do both: display the picture on the same page and see it while already beeing on the next page. You would have to submit the form via Ajax while staying on the same page.

And image should be used like `<img src="cookie.png" />` not `<img src="cookie.png"></img>`

And dont use `src="first script.js"` with whitespaces.. use `src="first-script.js"`

And do you even have jQuery included?

Comment: This should have been a comment. While true, this is only a small part of the problem *as the page refreshes!*

Comment: He only said he wants it to appear on submit?

Comment: Yes, but the options are to either process it server-side, or stop the submit.

Comment: Well then the submit will never happen. Stop downvoting, the question is just bad :(

Comment: I didn't say you downvoted me.. but now you did, congratulations!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I edited my answer, maybe you will like it more now

Comment: Still not complete as it cannot work as described (by you or the OP).

Comment: Would you upvote it now? Or do you think there is anything missing, lol

Answer (score -2):

I don't get why you want to `submit` without *actually* submitting anything, except if you want to *post* via Ajax (but you're going the wrong way then).

Yet, you need to use `preventDefault();` like this

```
$(document).ready(function()){
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent from submitting
        $('body').append('<img src="cookie.png" />');
    });
});
```

---

But this will load the image **after** you have clicked on the page ; which is not the best.

A better solution could be to have your image already loaded (but hidden) and just show it on the click:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Data tracking </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="first script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Track your data</h1> 
    <p>Would you like to know how many data a web site can track from you?</p> 
    <form method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal data</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
            <br>
            <input id= "submit" name= "submit" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
        <div></div>
    </form>

    <igm src="cookie.png" id="formImg" style="display:none;" />
</body>

$(document).ready(function()){
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent from submitting
        $("#formImg").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Already posted this and got downvoted for it (deleted since). This code also stops the form from submitting. Sorry.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie OP didn't say it should (or not) submit. An answer from the OP would be greatly appreciated though

Comment: A non-ajax form is pretty useless without a submit :) The OP has yet to explain anything... Moving on now (wasted more than enough time on this one) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That was the point of my first sentence: there is no point to use a form without actually submitting. Yet if one want to submit and display an image (or anything else), the way OP did is not the good one.